# Как установить приоритет отображение элементов?

Tags: java, javafx

Когда добавляю элемент вот по такому принципу:

```
root.getChildren().addAll();
```

То те элементы, что добавлены последними становятся сверх тех, что добавлены вначале, каким образом можно отрегулировать их приоритет отображения?

Comment: Укажите к каким языкам программирования, платформам и т.п. относится данный вопрос. Выбранный вами тег root применяется для вопросов касающихся привилигерованного пользователя в Unix системах. Ваш вопрос, очевидно к этому не относится

Comment: Приведите больше кода, чтобы было понятно, что и куда вы добавляете.

Comment: Root - это какой контейнер у тебя?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov root это pane

Comment: А почему ты не возьмешь конкретную реализацию, например, GridPane или BorderPane?

Answer (score 1):

можно баловаться методами toFront() и toBack()